# Django Rest Framework what is the best way to show more or less models fields in the response, base on the user request that makes the cal

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have several Apps serving a nice restful API with Django Rest Framework, love it.

My questios is, what is the best way to show more or less models fields in the response, base on the user request that makes the call, Thanks very much!, on this example I show you mi implementation, but doesn't seem very dry

In my views I need to decide what fields to show the user depending on the request User, so I have the following example:

```
class PostRetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    model = Post
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrAuthenticatedReadOnly,)

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        obj = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == obj.owner:
            if obj.draft:
                return LoggedUserPostDraftWriteSerializer
            return LoggedUserPostDraftReadSerializer
        return PostBaseSerializer
```

And the example of two serializer is:

```
class PostBaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('slug', 'title', 'content')
        read_only_fields = ('slug',)

class LoggedUserPostDraftReadSerializer(AnyModelBaseSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = AnyModel
        fields = ('slug', 'title', 'content', 'owner', 'is_draft', 'more_fields')
        read_only_fields = ('slug',)
```

I feel that I am not doing this right, should I attack this problem from the serializer point of view?

my questios is, what is the best way to show more or less models fields in the response, base on the user request that makes the call, Thanks very much!

Comment: this seems really sloppy. Your serializers and views should be tied to  the models they represent. Serializers are just a way to correctly send a necessary parts of model in JSON, and then, when receiving, return those parts to a fully functioning object. Using AnyModel defeats this concept. Serializers should also be intimately tied to their views, so that typical conventions like `user-list` and `user-detail` can be observed.

Comment: No, you are not getting my question "AnyModel" means not any model in django, it ment the example could be to my Blog model or my Post Model, I just didnt want to write my model name.

Your answer doesnt have to do with my question, my questios is, what is the best way to show more or less models fields in the response, base on the user request that makes the call.

I will update my question to avoid this confusion

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but I think [this link](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#dynamically-modifying-fields) is exactly what you need.

It explains how to build a dynamic serializer, which can take an extra argument 'fields', so that it can only return the fields you need.